# How to convert UTF8 NFC files to UTF8 NFD with convmv on Mac OS High Sierra?

Tags: utf-8, homebrew, macos-high-sierra, apfs

The new Mac OS High Sierra does not convert UTF8 NFC files to NFD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) on the file system layer (like the mac OS before did). Now I want to convert some files, because my app needs them in UTF8 NFD. This works on linux machines with convmv and this call:

```
convmv -r -f utf8 -t utf8 --nfd --notest path/
```

I installed convmv on Mac via homebrew and when I call the same I get:

```
*filename* exists and differs or --replace option missing - skipped
```

Seems like does not convert because of different file content, which makes no sense to me. I can run this again and again and "converts" every time. I tried with --replace, --exec, --nodouble

Comment: I do not use NFD anymore on mac os high sierra and on ubuntu, that does solve my problem, but not the desribed question. convmv mac os port is not writing to disk.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS High Sierra and it converts filename to NFD automatically. Actually that is my problem, when moving files from Mac to Linux, because on Linux you want to use NFC.